# how to receive JSONObject as response instead of string in android from soap web service

Tags: java, web-services, ksoap2

I have a web service that sends JSONObject as response but in Android, if I receive the json object response, an Exception occurs:

```
Oct 12, 2012 7:36:16 AM org.apache.axis.Message writeTo
SEVERE: java.io.IOException:
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.io.IOException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject in registry org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingDelegate@7275f5b7
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.io.IOException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject in registry org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingDelegate@7275f5b7
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.serializeActual(SerializationContext.java:1507)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.serialize(SerializationContext.java:980)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.serialize(SerializationContext.java:801)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCParam.serialize(RPCParam.java:208)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.outputImpl(RPCElement.java:433)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.output(MessageElement.java:1208)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPBody.outputImpl(SOAPBody.java:139)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPEnvelope.outputImpl(SOAPEnvelope.java:478)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.output(MessageElement.java:1208)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.writeTo(SOAPPart.java:315)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.writeTo(SOAPPart.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.writeTo(Message.java:539)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.sendResponse(AxisServlet.java:902)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:777)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:Kanmani-PC

java.io.IOException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject in registry org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingDelegate@7275f5b7
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.writeTo(SOAPPart.java:317)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.writeTo(SOAPPart.java:269)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.writeTo(Message.java:539)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.sendResponse(AxisServlet.java:902)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:777)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject in registry org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingDelegate@7275f5b7
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.serializeActual(SerializationContext.java:1507)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.serialize(SerializationContext.java:980)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.serialize(SerializationContext.java:801)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCParam.serialize(RPCParam.java:208)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.outputImpl(RPCElement.java:433)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.output(MessageElement.java:1208)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPBody.outputImpl(SOAPBody.java:139)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPEnvelope.outputImpl(SOAPEnvelope.java:478)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.output(MessageElement.java:1208)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.writeTo(SOAPPart.java:315)
    ... 19 more
```

**Can anyone help me know whether a JSONObject can be sent and received between web service and android client without the JSONObject being converted to a string ?**

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: i tried of sending the jsonobject from web service but am getting exception in android saying there is no serializer..

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me know whether a JSONObject can be sent and received between web service and android client without the JSONObject being converted to a string ?

No, it can't. If it's not sent as a string, it's not JSON. (excluding any compression or encryption used in the communication).